# Differences between New/CreateObject() vs EntityNew() in CF9 for persistent CFC?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

What are the differences (if any) between New/CreateObject() to create an object vs EntityNew() to create an entity in CF9 for persistent CFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoted from: [Learning ColdFusion 9: EntityNew() vs. The NEW Operator / CreateObject()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1687-Learning-ColdFusion-9-EntityNew-vs-The-NEW-Operator-CreateObject-.htm)

> I actually asked this question during
>   the "Advanced ORM" session at CFUNITED
>   and got a slightly different answer.
>   The speaker (forgive me for not
>   remembering his name - I think he was
>   the head Adobe engineer), told me that
>   when you load an object using
>   EntityNew(), ColdFusion actually
>   presents it in a slightly different
>   way than a standard CFC. While this
>   difference is not noticeable to the
>   programmer, a component created using
>   EntityNew() does afford some
>   efficiencies at the Hibernate
>   integration level. As such, he
>   recommended that all new ORM-enabled
>   objects be created with EntityNew().

Comment: It'd be excellent if there was actually more than second-hand anecdotal "evidence" of this. I might chase some up.

Answer (score 3):

With New() and CreateObject() you need to specify the full path to the CFC.

With EntityNew() you just need to pass in the name of the entity.